# Why data shown as line/circle instead of like 'ball' on t-SNE visualization?

Tags: python, data-science, data-visualization, data-analysis, feature-extraction

I'm currently using t-SNE to visualize data features.
First, I extracted the features vector from my model.

```
import torch.nn as nn

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d((1, 2), stride=2)
        self.normalize1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.normalize2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(6,16, (1, 6))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16,32, (1, 6))

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 1 * 20, 70)     
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(70, 30)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 19)
        self.drop1 = nn.Dropout2d(p=0.25) 

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.normalize1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.normalize2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = x.view(x.size()[0], -1)
        feature1 = x
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return feature1
```

Draw with TSNE:

`tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=30, learning_rate=200, n_iter=1000).fit_transform(features_1[::2])`

The result looks like this:
[image: Results of t-SNE Perplexity=30, Learning rate=200, n_iter=1000]

Does anyone know what causes the data features to look like a line or circle instead of a 'lump'?
(I think the data features from the same class should gather together as a lump?)

Is there anything I can do to fix it? Or is the result normal?

For your information, the test accuracy of my model is around 0.69, which seems like telling me my model is doing ok.

Comment: Have you tried with another dimensionality reduction technique, such as umap? https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap

Comment: No, I haven't try another one. May I know why you think that I should try another method?

Comment: Somewhat unlikely, but your data might be in high-dimensional uniform distributions. I'm wondering if another method (which applies other kinds of non-linearities and has different assumptions over the data) would yield a similar result.

Comment: By the way, you don't always get blobs: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.07860.pdf (page 8)